# vim: command like f{char} but for series of chars instead of single char

Tags: vim

In vim I can navigate to char in current line using f{char} -- To [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right. The cursor is placed on {char} (inclusive).

Lets look on next line:

```
from fmodule import futility
```

-- there are three words starting from `f` letter and assume that I want to jump to `futils`. To do it (with cursor at the beginning of line) I will execute `2ff`, but instead I would really like to do something like `f{fut}` (providing first char**s** of word not single one).

What are the ways to accomplish this task?

Comment: is `/fu<cr>` ok for you?

Comment: In some sense -- yes. But ideally I want limit this search to current line only (I can mistype chars and vim will find needed word somewhere in my code but far far away from current line :)). Also /fu<cr> will highlight all occurrences ... which is quite distracting.

Comment: you can write a function to do what you want, but you may want to check the EasyMotion plugin, it allows you to move to which `f`.  In your case, you  could use the `<leader><leader>f` or `<leader><leader>w` provided by EasyMotion.

Comment: If you jump to an unwanted position you can go back with `\`\``.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `/` search as a motion, also in visual mode and in combination with a command like `d`. You need to conclude the search with `<Enter>`, as usual. In contrast to `f`, this will also find matches in following lines. Some consider this a feature (and change `f` accordingly via plugins), others don't like this. If you're in the latter camp, the following mapping will restrict the pattern to the current line automatically:

```
noremap <expr> <Leader>/ '/\%' . line('.') . 'l'
```

You might also want to define `<Leader>?` for the opposite direction.